# SSH public/private key authentication is failing

Tags: linux, git, authentication, ubuntu, ssh

I have two instances (host names are namenode and datanode1 ) of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on Google compute engine.
I am struggling setting up ssh root access to between them.

I am providing some information so you can help me solve this issue

I generated the key pair (namenode, namenode.pub) on namenode. The public key on namenode looks like this

```
root@namenode:~# cat .ssh/namenode.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsxYETzfP3Kv9QgRZ5AnJGu6LNTuAJj67DhUzJVad1Cis7qQ7X7GSv1S+HQESiK/H1u3duVunMB+eiV1ktF/V42r5o3HCTTckiChSuu4B+wkHCqaHFYtGJZIMncPb4CvuyhzPz+Zb
mlV7YRGqw5lO+cQLSxCQpmBkIR1iQHRbtLIRenUTI3cXnJ22OhRea63R1/d+LspJreI8lnfmVLMr3MLUfi/U2vX3kR2EaH1QAoO1+dnRzuqsZE/ehbzT/DfBifRdoRCzhXuWgNKNxc/O0V3MwflnvPaWxxDC7FNQ7//nFg4gl8j4yV8
XFvuCyzJTQ9nS3wN+6Dms7MfDQtl4v root@namenode
```

I added this public key to datanode1's authorized keys.

```
root@datanode1:~# cat .ssh/authorized_keys 
# namenode
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsxYETzfP3Kv9QgRZ5AnJGu6LNTuAJj67DhUzJVad1Cis7qQ7X7GSv1S+HQESiK/H1u3duVunMB
+eiV1ktF/V42r5o3HCTTckiChSuu4B+wkHCqaHFYtGJZIMncPb4CvuyhzPz+ZbmlV7YRGqw5lO+cQLSxCQpmBkIR1iQHRbtLIRenUTI3cXnJ22OhR
ea63R1/d+LspJreI8lnfmVLMr3MLUfi/U2vX3kR2EaH1QAoO1+dnRzuqsZE/ehbzT/DfBifRdoRCzhXuWgNKNxc/O0V3MwflnvPaWxxDC7FNQ7//n
Fg4gl8j4yV8XFvuCyzJTQ9nS3wN+6Dms7MfDQtl4v root@namenode
```

I addded the identity like this

```
root@namenode:~# eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 4030
root@namenode:~# ssh-add .ssh/namenode
Identity added: .ssh/namenode (.ssh/namenode)
```

this is the verbose output

```
root@namenode:~# ssh -v -i .ssh/namenode.pub root@datanode1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to datanode1 [10.240.218.126] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file .ssh/namenode.pub type 1
debug1: identity file .ssh/namenode.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b8:70:6e:f6:8c:4e:8e:ed:2b:46:d6:d4:d9:4d:ec:bb
debug1: Host 'datanode1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/namenode.pub
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please help me solve this. I have been struggling since 2 days.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the destination server?

Comment: -rw------- 1 root root 3695 Mar 19 18:53 .ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: It looks like users other than root cannot read the file. should I change the permissions sir?

Comment: No, that is actually good.  sshd will complain if the file is readable by other users.

Comment: Also, this question might be better suited to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thank you. I asked the question in serverfault.com as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -v -i .ssh/namenode.pub root@datanode1
```

When you specify an ssh key on the command line, it should be the private key file, not the public file. So you should reference `.ssh/namenode` here, not `.ssh/namenode.pub`.

It looks like you added the private key to `ssh-add`, but there's no indication in the ssh debug trace that it communicated with the ssh agent or offered the private key to the remote server. Perhaps you ran ssh in a different session (terminal window) from the ssh-add command, so that ssh didn't have access to the environment variables telling it how to access the agent.

Finally, the contents of the `namenode.pub` line is one long line. Make sure you copied it into the remote `authorized_keys` file as one long line, instead of three lines.